# How to make sure a pair of items in np.random.choice don't appear together in a loop?

Tags: python, numpy, montecarlo

I'm currently trying to run a MonteCarlo simulation without replacement, using np.random.choice, but there are certain items in the list which cannot appear together. For example, if I have a list of five items: RO, MI, VE,NA, SI, and each loop produces a group of four items, RO can appear with VE, MI, or NA, but it cannot appear with SI, on each iteration.
So a loop like: [RO,MI,VE,NA] is correct
But not: [RO,MI,SI,NA] as SI appears in the same group as RO.
This is the code I'm currently using (which is producing the incorrect grouping):

```
np.random.seed(42)
portfolio=[]
for i in range(0,10000):
    port_gar = list(np.random.choice(cities, size=4, replace=False, p=cities_prob))
    portfolio.append(port_gar)
print(portfolio)
```

I'm at a loss as to what would do and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why not separate the cities into two groups: ones that can mix-and-match together without constraint, and all the cities that cannot be grouped together in their own list. Then grab X items from the cities that can mix, and then one item from the cities that don't play nice.

Comment: @blorgon Yes, I actually have about 300, but used five as an example! I thought about putting an if statement after the random.choice to state that if two items do not appear together in the group, to  append that group to the second list (portfolio). But I'm not sure if that would work with multiple exceptions :/

Comment: @blorgon `replace=False` guarantees unique items if there are at least `size` unique items in the list.

Comment: Yep @trevor-pope , I was thinking of the built-in `choice`.

Comment: @DoraAdrianaCordero do you have a LOT of different constraints? Or is it just one list of cities *none of which* can be together? I.e., do you have *multiple* groups of cities that can't match with each other? Like `ro, si` and maybe another group like `ij, xy`?

Comment: @blorgon I have three pairs of cities, within the list, which cannot appear together in the generated group, but they can appear with other cities in the list. So for example in a list of 300 cities, RO cannot appear with NA, NA cannot appear with VE, and RO cannot appear with VE. But it's fine if any of these three appear with all other cities in the same group. (Hope that made sense)

Comment: I've updated my solution with this in mind.

Comment: In that case, if I'm understanding correctly, I'd suggest putting `RO, VE, NA` in a group together, and choosing ONE item from that group. Then mix that in with the others.

Comment: @Adorable I know you already accepted an answer, but I'd suggest taking a look at the one I just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I present two solutions, both of which make use of the `random` module from the standard library. I recommend this approach over using numpy since you can't really take advantage of numpy here in any way, and especially because you're not even ending up with a numpy array at the end (you're *only* using numpy for random number generation).

## Solution 1: every sample has *exactly one* city from the "exclusive cities" group

Something you could do is have your cities which don't play nice in a separate group from the others:

```py
import random
random.seed(42)


n = 10  # whatever total number of items you want per sample
num_samples = 10000  # total number of samples


free_cities = [...]  # all cities in this group play nicely together
exclusive_cities = [...]  # cities in this group cannot be grouped in a sample, so we will only ever choose one city at a time from this group


portfolio = []
for _ in range(num_samples):
    free_sample = random.sample(free_cities, k=(n-1))
    exclusive_sample = random.sample(exclusive_cities, k=1)
    portfolio.append(random.sample(free_sample + exclusive_sample, k=n))
```

Here's a contrived example:

```py
n = 6
num_samples = 10

free_cities = ["AW", "JB", "EX", "HZ", "MZ", "XQ", "KA", "MW", "WZ", "UD"]
exclusive_cities = ["RO", "VE", "SI", "NA"]


portfolio = []
for _ in range(num_samples):
    free_sample = random.sample(free_cities, k=(n-1))
    exclusive_sample = random.sample(exclusive_cities, k=1)
    portfolio.append(random.sample(free_sample + exclusive_sample, k=n))
```

Output:

```py
>>> portfolio
[['AW', 'EX', 'WZ', 'RO', 'MZ', 'JB'],
 ['RO', 'MZ', 'KA', 'WZ', 'XQ', 'EX'],
 ['AW', 'MW', 'VE', 'JB', 'WZ', 'XQ'],
 ['NA', 'WZ', 'JB', 'MW', 'EX', 'MZ'],
 ['SI', 'UD', 'AW', 'JB', 'WZ', 'MW'],
 ['MZ', 'JB', 'UD', 'VE', 'WZ', 'HZ'],
 ['NA', 'KA', 'UD', 'AW', 'MW', 'WZ'],
 ['JB', 'NA', 'UD', 'KA', 'WZ', 'MW'],
 ['MZ', 'RO', 'JB', 'HZ', 'AW', 'XQ'],
 ['WZ', 'HZ', 'UD', 'JB', 'VE', 'XQ']]
```

Now something to be aware of is that this will guarantee that every sample has exactly one city from the `exclusive_cities` group:

```py
for sample in portfolio:
    print(set(sample) & set(exclusive_cities))
```

Output:

```py
# Every sample has one item from the exclusive_cities group
{'RO'}
{'RO'}
{'VE'}
{'NA'}
{'SI'}
{'VE'}
{'NA'}
{'NA'}
{'RO'}
{'VE'}
```

## Solution 2: every sample has *at most one* city from the "exclusive cities" group

If that's not your desired behavior, you can use an additional "coin flip" to determine if 1 or 0 exclusive cities show up in a given sample with this minor modification to the above logic:

```py
n = 6
num_samples = 10


portfolio = []
for _ in range(num_samples):
    include = random.choice((0, 1))
    free_sample = random.sample(free_cities, k=(n - include))
    exclusive_sample = random.sample(exclusive_cities, k=include)
    portfolio.append(random.sample(free_sample + exclusive_sample, k=n))
```

Now your samples may or may not include an exclusive city, but still only ever one max:

```py
# An empty set means an exclusive city isn't present in that sample
set()
set()
{'SI'}
{'NA'}
set()
{'RO'}
{'SI'}
{'VE'}
set()
{'RO'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the constraints on which cities can appear in the list, the simplest solution might be to randomly generate cities until you have enough of them that are valid. For example:

```
def check_valid(port_gar):
    is_valid = True
    
    if 'RO' in port_gar:
        is_valid = is_valid and ('NA' not in port_gar and 'VE' not in port_gar)
    if 'NA' in port_gar:
        is_valid = is_valid and 'VE' not in port_gar
    
    # Add other checks for constraints here

    return is_valid

portfolio = []
while len(portfolio) < 10000:
    port_gar = list(np.random.choice(cities, size=4, replace=False, p=cities_prob))
    if check_valid(port_gar):
        portfolio.append(port_gar)

print(portfolio)
```

This is definitely not the most efficient implementation, but if the number of samples is relatively small (in this case, 10000) and the number of cities is large, then the performance should be fine.

Comment: It would be much better to run a counter that increments every time a sample is appended to `portfolio`, that way you're not calling `len` every iteration, which is extremely inefficient.

Comment: Agreed, and the if statements could be improved so we don't include repeat checks. I'll update it later